# I don't understand this remark regarding Weierstrass' Theorem (Ahlfors' Complex Analysis)

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, compactness, uniform-convergence

In Ahlfors' text of Complex Analysis, chapter 5 theorem 1, he proves the following:

> Theorem I.    Suppose that $f_n(z)$ is analytic in the region $\Omega_n$, and that the sequence $\{f_n(z)\}$ converges to a limit function $f(z)$ in a region $\Omega$, uniformly on every compact subset of $\Omega$. Then $f(z)$ is analytic in $\Omega$. Moreover, $f_n'(z)$ converges uniformly to $f' (z)$ on every compact subset of $\Omega$.

In the proof he examines a closed disk $|z-a| \leq r$ which is contained in $\Omega$. He claims that from the assumptions of the theorem the disk lies in all $\Omega_n$ for $n>n_0$ for some $n_0$.( I think this is clear, due to the uniform convergence on compact subsets.) Under this sentence there is a footnote which states:

> In fact, the regions $\Omega_n$. form an open covering of $|z - a| \leq r$. The disk is compact and hence has a finite subcovering. This means that it is contained in a fixed $\Omega_{n_0}$.

I don't see the need for this footnote: above we already saw that the disk lies in each of the domains $\Omega_{n_0+1},\Omega_{n_0+2}, \dots$, so clearly it lies within some domain of the $\Omega_n$'s.

What am I doing wrong here? Thanks.

EDIT: actually, I can't see how it that remark correct. Even if there is a finite subcovering of the disk $\{\Omega_{n_k} \}_{k=1}^N$, why should it lie in a *single* disk $\Omega_{n_0}$?

Comment: An aside; this theorem is a combination of Theorems 7.6 and 10.12 from Bak and Newman. There is no similar such mention, and the remark seems to be more confusing than helpful. Do note, however, that $\Omega_{n_0}$ is a region, which is not necessarily a disk.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right: the footnote is both unnecessary and confusing.

- Unnecessary because in the theorem we assume $f_n\to f$ uniformly on every compact subset of $\Omega$. This (implicitly) contains the assumption that every compact subset of $\Omega$ lies within the domain of $f_n$ for all sufficiently large $n$.
- Confusing because "it is contained in a single $\Omega_{n_0}$" is not  what the proof needs; we need the disk to be contained in $\Omega_n$ for all $n\ge n_0$.
- Also confusing because "it is contained in a single $\Omega_{n_0}$" does not follow from the definition of a compact set, as the remark appears to suggest.

Verdict: disregard the footnote, continue reading the proof.

Comment: Thank you. Do you think he had something else in mind, and wrote this instead?

Comment: @user1337 Yes, I think he thought of the proof that if $\Omega$ is the union of nested (increasing) sequence of domains $\Omega_n$, then every compact subset of $\Omega$ is contained in a single $\Omega_{n_0}$ (hence in all bigger ones).

Comment: Brilliant! ${}$